# ActionController Routing Error on Rails 6 w/ Webpack and Yarn

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, docker, webpack, puma

First time configuring a production rails app with react and webpack. I am trying to understand the structure needed for webpack controlled by rails to statically serve my assets. Currently running into what may be a silly error in my webpacker.yml configuration. Greatly appreciate any help with this!

Error from log/production.log after setting up pod running rails s -e production:

```
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:38.761451 #99155]  INFO -- : [3a2db351-9e29-49a1-86fd-c86aae7d7170] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-09-12 15:44:38 -0700
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:38.773079 #99155]  INFO -- : [3a2db351-9e29-49a1-86fd-c86aae7d7170] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:38.782973 #99155]  INFO -- : [3a2db351-9e29-49a1-86fd-c86aae7d7170]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:38.784041 #99155]  INFO -- : [3a2db351-9e29-49a1-86fd-c86aae7d7170]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 529)
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:38.784881 #99155]  INFO -- : [3a2db351-9e29-49a1-86fd-c86aae7d7170] Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 4.2ms | Allocations: 5206)
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:38.905772 #99155]  INFO -- : [96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] Started GET "/assets/application-5abc9724d464865c6ee8976394f0a5c56c7146787659b1e3a4a7ab5e5aaa4286.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-09-12 15:44:38 -0700
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:38.908708 #99155]  INFO -- : [7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] Started GET "/packs/js/application-fc1aefbe06067b06814f.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-09-12 15:44:38 -0700
F, [2021-09-12T15:44:39.064063 #99155] FATAL -- : [96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8]   
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-5abc9724d464865c6ee8976394f0a5c56c7146787659b1e3a4a7ab5e5aaa4286.css"):
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8]   
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
[96ccf555-b82c-443e-9244-807aab47e7f8] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
F, [2021-09-12T15:44:39.065224 #99155] FATAL -- : [7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1]   
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/js/application-fc1aefbe06067b06814f.js"):
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1]   
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
[7c4c2892-b369-424f-8372-a0976d15bbf1] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:41.937094 #99155]  INFO -- : [6d0d2df9-6526-4496-94aa-ae73ebcc89be] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-09-12 15:44:41 -0700
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:41.949275 #99155]  INFO -- : [6d0d2df9-6526-4496-94aa-ae73ebcc89be] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:41.951191 #99155]  INFO -- : [6d0d2df9-6526-4496-94aa-ae73ebcc89be]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:41.951576 #99155]  INFO -- : [6d0d2df9-6526-4496-94aa-ae73ebcc89be]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 135)
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:41.952493 #99155]  INFO -- : [6d0d2df9-6526-4496-94aa-ae73ebcc89be] Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.7ms | Allocations: 1024)
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:42.005012 #99155]  INFO -- : [501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] Started GET "/assets/application-5abc9724d464865c6ee8976394f0a5c56c7146787659b1e3a4a7ab5e5aaa4286.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-09-12 15:44:42 -0700
I, [2021-09-12T15:44:42.016207 #99155]  INFO -- : [ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] Started GET "/packs/js/application-fc1aefbe06067b06814f.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-09-12 15:44:42 -0700
F, [2021-09-12T15:44:42.029960 #99155] FATAL -- : [501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12]   
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-5abc9724d464865c6ee8976394f0a5c56c7146787659b1e3a4a7ab5e5aaa4286.css"):
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12]   
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
[501b9eb7-d4c6-49f0-89fc-cc95a846cd12] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
F, [2021-09-12T15:44:42.031569 #99155] FATAL -- : [ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c]   
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/js/application-fc1aefbe06067b06814f.js"):
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c]   
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] activesupport (6.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] actionpack (6.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] railties (6.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
[ec8802fc-a274-4154-893a-4eed2d44565c] puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Webpacker.yml (also have a webpack.config.js?):

```
    # Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

webpack.config.js:

```
// Generated using webpack-cli https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli

const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';


const stylesHandler = isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader';



const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    plugins: [
        // Add your plugins here
        // Learn more about plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [stylesHandler, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset',
            },

            // Add your rules for custom modules here
            // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
        ],
    },
};

module.exports = () => {
    if (isProduction) {
        config.mode = 'production';
        
        config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin());

        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
        }

    } else {
        config.mode = 'development';
    }
    return config;
};
```

application.js located in (app/assets/javascript/packs):

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

Portion of Dockerfile commands for webpacker on rails:

```
RUN rails webpacker:install
RUN rails webpacker:install:react
RUN gem list
RUN yarn install
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec rails s -e production
```

I imagine the error is something to do with my file structure and where webpacker/rails is looking to fetch the assets from. Currently with react in my app/assets/javascript folder I have the standard components, also a home folder inside views with index.html.erb with the appropriately listed javascript_pack_tag for my home page components. Wondering if I am missing something simple in my entrypoint for running webpack or if it's just a folder config error?

Please let me know if further info is needed, running rails 6, webpack 5+. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you react js in the folder `app/assets/javascript` but your webpacker config `source_path` point to `app/javascript`

```rb
# config/webpacker.yml
default: &default
  source_path: javascript # -> app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs # -> app/javascript/packs
  public_output_path: packs
```

`webpacker` will try to compile all `app/javascript/packs/*.js` files but could not find anything (in your case) so there's no .js (ex: `application.js`) output file.

when the web open, `javascript_pack_tag application` will look for `application.js` in the `public_output_path` but couldn't see it.

you could try to change the source directory from `app/javascript` to `app/assets/javascript` as below

```rb
# config/webpacker.yml
default: &default
  source_path: app/assets/javascript 
  source_entry_path: packs
```

Note: you could run `bundle exec rails webpacker:compile` to test webpack compilation failed or not.